# The following is a python code for a program of rolling dice. But pycharm is not asking for input

Tags: python-3.x

```
class Dice:
    def roll(self):
        import random
        msg=input("Roll the dice")
       [enter image description here][1] msgs = msg.lower()
        while msgs != "exit()":
            if msgs == "roll()" :
                x=(random.randint(1,7))
                y=(random.randint(1, 7))
                print(x,y)
            elif msgs == "help()" :
                '''
                Type roll() to roll
                     exit() to exit
                '''
            else :
                "invalid msg, type help() for help"
```

[image: some-title]

Comment: Can you show a minimal reproducible example of your code? Thanks

Comment: You don't start anything here, this is just a class definition.

Answer (score 0):

for this you need to create object of `Dice` class and call the `roll` function for the same.

```py
dice = Dice()
dice.roll()
```